# Django ORM - Filter by GenericRelation across multiple models

Tags: django, django-generic-relations

Filtering on Django GenericRelations has been implemented 4 years ago via https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22207 and supports now to filter from the related model:

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    project_content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
    project_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=True)
    project = GenericForeignKey('project_content_type', 'project_id')

class GitlabProject(models.Model):
    issues = GenericRelation(
        Issue,
        related_query_name='generic_project',
        content_type_field='project_content_type',
        object_id_field='project_id',
)
```

and then:

```
issues = queryset.filter(generic_project__offers__members__in=[request.user])
```

We cannot use just `project__offers_members` - it would fail, as Django does not reversely resolve Generic Foreign Keys.

However what happens if we have another project model with the same `related_query_name`?

```
class JiraProject(models.Model):
    issues = GenericRelation(
        Issue,
        related_query_name='generic_project',
        content_type_field='project_content_type',
        object_id_field='project_id',
)
```

I have tried setting the `GenericRelation` with the same `related_query_name` on all the different `project` models (i.e. Gitlab Project, Jira Project, etc.). However that results in Django picking up only the 'first' project model. The generic relation to all subsequent project models are ignored and as a result, issues that have instances set that do not belong to the 'first' project model are ignored and not part of the queryset.

I think Django should either support this or issue a warning or error (possibly when executing the makemigrations command), when multiple GenericRelations have the same `related_query_name` value set.

How can one filter efficiently across `issues` that have their `project` attribute set to instances of different models?